# Can we use JavascriptExecutor for Appium scripts also? If yes can you guide me?

Tags: selenium, appium, highlight

I want to use JavascriptExecutor for highlight while Appium & Selenium script is going to executing on a real mobile device. but getting some issue.

Can we use JavascriptExecutor for Appium scripts also? If yes can you guide me?

```
public class HighlightTesting {
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = null;
ObjectRepository or;
 @Test
public void sslWebApp() throws Exception {
    String workspace=System.getProperty("user.dir");
    //Set the Desired Capabilities
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Samba");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "28a950650404"); //Give Device ID of your mobile phone
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.0");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", true);
    caps.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "shoppersstop.shoppersstop");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity","com.shoppersstop.apps.ui.splash.SplashActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement> (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    new BaseClass(driver);
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println("Welcome to Shoppersstop mobile App");
    WebElement el=driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@resource-id='shoppersstop.shoppersstop:id/imageview_circular_widget_item'])[3]"));
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", el);
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println("Done");
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way of highlighting the elements will work only for:

1. Mobile Web Browsers
2. [WebView](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted)-based applications

Looking into the following lines:

```
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "shoppersstop.shoppersstop");
caps.setCapability("appActivity","com.shoppersstop.apps.ui.splash.SplashActivity");
```

it seems that you're testing native Android application therefore you're limited to [Mobile Commands](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/) which are supported by Appium natively and eventually some extras available via [SeeTest - Appium Extensions](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension)

If you need to test your locators you can use either [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop) or [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) or [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/) or [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)